# ON DELETE SET <value>

Tags: oracle, alter-table

I'm new to database query execution. Here is my query-

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE123 ADD (
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (TABLE_ID) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (TABLE_ID)
    ON DELETE SET 0
);
```

When I execute this, I get this error message-

```
Error starting at line 5 in command:
ALTER TABLE TABLE123 ADD (
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (TABLE_ID) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (TABLE_ID)
    ON DELETE SET 0
);
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword
00908. 00000 -  "missing NULL keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Then I tried this-

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE123 MODIFY TABLE_ID DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL REEFRENCES PARENT_TABLE (TABLE_ID) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;
```

I got this error message-

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.
```

Comment: `ON DELETE` only allows `SET NULL`. Please [read the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's `on delete` clause only supports `set null`. If you want to set a different value, you'd have to implement it yourself in a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER parent_table_del_tr
BEFORE DELETE ON parent_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE table123
    SET    table_id = 0
    WHERE  table_id = :OLD.table_id;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks. According to the trigger, I want to update and set id to 0 only when it is null. When I do that, I get the error message - 
`04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.`